# Does Convergence in distribution imply convergence of integral?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

If $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of integrable functions on $(0,1)$ such that $\sup_{n\geq 1}|f_n|$ is a well defined measurable function, and if $f_n \rightarrow f$ in distribution, does $\int_0^1 f_n \rightarrow \int_0^1 f$?

I haven't been able to construct a counterexample, so I'm thinking that it is correct. I've been told that convergence in distribution is essentially the same as point wise convergence of characteristic functions, so we have that $\int_0^1 e^{-it f_n} \rightarrow \int_0^1 e^{-it f}$ point wise. So I'm hoping that I can use this expression to determine that $f_n$ must be monotone, and hence use the montane convergence theorem.

I'd love to know if this is a good approach, and how it would be done from here! Alternatively, I would also be down for some alternate suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(x)=n\chi_{(0,\frac  1n)}, f(x)=0$ is a counter-example. It is bounded by $\frac 1 x$ which is a well-defined measurable function.

Comment: That seems so obvious, of course! Thank you very much!